# How do I calculate the relative permittivity of a capacitor given when only given 2 charges?

Tags: capacitance

I have a past paper question which gives me the  external charge of this [capacitor](https://gyazo.com/7b169dc572f7ee5f97ceb8efe625fbf9) 7.1μC and the internal charge caused by the resultant field as 1.3μC, how do I calculate the relative permittivity? 
I thought it would have just been Q1/Q2 but according to the mark scheme that's not the case.

Comment: if you explain, why you thought what you thought, we can point you to where it's wrong. This will help most if you are interested in an explanation rather that the mere result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C=Q/V$ deals with quantities that can be seen from outside: if you connect your device to a voltage, there will be some amount of charge that it will hold till it is "full".
In your problem one of the charges is the internal charge, which is something different. Think about what it does: you have some charge on the plates of the capacitor, and the charge from within comes near the plates too to screen it (partially).
The charge that has flown into the capacitor through the cables is still the same! But something (what exactly?) happened.
Hint: consider a piece of metal incide. A dielectric is something between a metal and vacuum.

Comment: So the electric field values are the same, but the charge value of the second charge is different as it has a dielectric constant? but then would this not simplify to the internal charge/external charge = relative permittivity?

Comment: what do you mean by "second charge"? There is one charge you can measure from outside, and some more charge inside that does some magic there. Indeed, it's not magic. It does the same as the outside charge, with the only difference that it is hidden and is not counted as charge from without...

Comment: You cannot just insert *some* values which are represented by a letter $Q$ in any formula with charge :) Try to get it clear what is happening! What does charge do? and so on...

Comment: ahhh I understand now! it's okay, I see that that E0 = Q0/ε, and that if the electric field within is going against it the resultant would be-  ER = E0 - Ei! thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah, well. Good, that you had the patience to understand it and not just to search for a quick answer :) Good luck further!

Answer (score 0):

The relative permittivity is the ratio of the electric field in a vacuum (due to the charge 7.1 $\mu$C) and the electric field with the dielectric present due to the original charge and the induced charge.